# opengl vertext shader error: Too much data in type constructor

Tags: opengl, shader

Please, help. What's problem in simple vertex shader code below.
0(12) : error C1068: too much data in type constructor

```
#version 450

void main()
{   
    const vec2[6] Q = { vec2(-0.5,-0.5),
                        vec2( 0.5,-0.5),
                        vec2(-0.5, 0.5),

                        vec2(-0.5, 0.5),
                        vec2( 0.5,-0.5),
                        vec2( 0,5, 0.5)
    };
    gl_Position = vec4(
        Q[ gl_VertexID ].x,
        Q[ gl_VertexID ].y,
        0.0,
        1.0
    );
}
```

Comment: Read about [Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)) - focus on the chapters "Initializer lists" and "Array constructors".

Answer (score 3):

You can initialise an array in glsl like this (similar to C++11):

```
const vec2 Q[6] = { 
    { -0.5, -0.5 },
    {  0.5, -0.5 },
    { -0.5,  0.5 },
    { -0.5,  0.5 },
    {  0.5, -0.5 },
    {  0.5,  0.5 }
};
```

Not sure if you noticed the deliberate error in your example.  The last line has a comma where it should have a ".".